# net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, bootstrap-4

When I run the project I get the error in the attached image.

I already checked if those files in those folder exist, everything is there. I don't understand how to solve this problem.

this is the code

```html
<link href="Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Content/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Content/css/main.css?rndstr=<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>" rel="stylesheet"  />
<% if (Session["isMobile"].ToString() != "true") { %>
<link href="Content/css/pccss.css?rndstr=<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>" rel="stylesheet">
<% } else { %>
<link href="Content/css/mobilecss.css?rndstr=<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>" rel="stylesheet">
<% } %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery/jquery.color.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin-master/jquery.touchSwipe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/object/components/bAlert.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: You are getting http error 500.  The server doesn't like the format of the request. If you have a wroking application use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare a working applications against your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the error stacktrace as text.

Comment: @Chris Garcia, Were you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "." or ".." in your urls . If it's necessary use "~" in your url's to help locate them in your host application as relative location.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is Probably from the file you uploaded or linked to your application.

Debugging Strategy:
Try Loading the file directly using its link.

Trying to access one of these static files directly also fails and just shows the message “The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Solutions:
In some cases, the site might be referencing the FontAwesome package which uses the WOFF file type. This happens when your server is using an older version Tech than you are using. In the older version this MIME type was not registered so it required a manual entry in the configuration. In the newer IIS, this is handled natively, and the manual configuration is now causing a problem rather than remediating one.

Check the web.config file for a reference to woff(or Filetype)

for example:

and comment out or remove this line.

Refresh the page in your browser and it should now load correctly.

see more here: https://www.isjw.uk/post/software/css-javascript-image-500-error-iis/